# LiquidXML DataBinding Suppress NodeType when exporting to XML String

Tags: xml, liquid-xml

I use LiquidXML. I have a XSD file, this XSD File created a Visual Basic .Net project via the DataBinder tool.
Now I create the classes and export them via xxx.ToXML
The created Xml string looks good so far. But I get some of the nodes like this:

```
<pair>
            <patient xs:type="Patient">
                <id memberShipID="1"/>
                <name>xxx </name>
            </patient>
```

How can I create the export that way, that the patient node does NOT include the xs:type="Patient" NodeType?

THX a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [WriteTypeAttribute](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Reference/XmlDataBinding/index.html?/Reference/XmlDataBinding/source/API/DotNet/XmlSerializationContext/WriteTypeAttribute.HTM) to False in the Default XmlSerializationContext:

**VB .Net**

```
LiquidTechnologies.Runtime.Net45.SerializationContext.Default.WriteTypeAttribute = False
```

**C#**

```
LiquidTechnologies.Runtime.Net45.SerializationContext.Default.WriteTypeAttribute = false;
```

**C++**

```
LtXmlLib16::CSerializationContext::GetDefaultContext().SetWriteTypeAttribute(false);
```

**Java**

```
com.liquid_technologies.ltxmllib16.SerializationContext.Default.setWriteTypeAttribute(false);
```

**Please note** the generator only adds xsi:type for derived types. Depending on your XML Schema, the xsi:type may need to be present in the XML Document in order for a parser to know which derived item is been used. This is described in the article '[Using the xsi:type Attribute](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-schema-tutorial/xsd-extending-types#xsi-type)'.